# Render the same form in template with initial data

Tags: django

I'a stuck with the following problem.
I an Employer model, an Employee model, an HourCode model and a ReportModel.

I will begin with the outcome i want to see, maybe then its clear what iam asking.
Every employee has a employer and every employer has hourCodes for time registration.
For Example: John is working at xerox, he worked 10 normal hours and 5 extra hours. In this case the hourcode are "normal hours" and " extra hours ".
In my template i want to render a sort of table view so that de hours can be filled by the employer. So in this case he had to fill in 10 hours on "normal hours" and 5 hours on "extra hours" at John.
But, the employer has ofcourse multiple employees, so he has to fill in several lines with the worked hours and extra hours per employee.

Employeename.  Normal hours. Extra hours

John.           10.              5
Eva.             3.              5

SaveButton

After savebutton pressed the forms (in this case 2, each for every employee) has to be saved to the ReportModel. The Reportmodel has some fields (ForeignKey fields to employer, employee and hourcodes.

Long story, my question how can i render the view in the template such as above with John and eva. So with the initial values of the employees and hourcodes.

I already have tried formsets but i cant get the initials on all the forms.
Any advise will be helpfull, i dont have to get code but just a punch in the right way

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want the data from your models to be available when you fill a new form.

To do this, you can find the instance of a model you wish to edit, then you can then edit the form if you wish to.

Here's an example:

```
def AddHours(request):
    template = ReportModel.objects.get(pk=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ExampleForm(request.POST, instance=template)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = ExampleForm(instance=template)
    return render(request, 'example/template.html', {'form':form})
```

Comment: No i want to render my form serval times with a save button, in sort of row look (like excel). So each row is my form, and then 30 times. But each row i have to save to my model

Comment: So you want to have the form save the data several times? If it's that, you could maybe try writing form.save() the number of times you want it to save, or add a loop.